# Angular Universal Update from v7 to v8

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have recently updated my project from angular 7 to 8 with ng update. All work fine but i figured out that Angular Universal is not updated to version 8.

When i check my ng update i have this line

```
ng update @nguniversal/aspnetcore-engine
```

But that following error when i try to update :

```
Package '@nguniversal/aspnetcore-engine' is not a dependency.
```

Angular Universal is not updated and Here my package.json. How can i update Angular Universal and why it's not possible with ng update.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/pwa": "~0.803.23",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/service-worker": "8.2.14",
    "@ngrx/effects": "8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "8.6.0",
    "@nguniversal/common": "^7.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^7.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "@taoqf/javascript-state-machine": "^3.0.8",
    "angular7-csv": "^0.2.12",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.10",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.4.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.2.0",
    "ngx-captcha": "^6.4.0",
    "ngx-cookie": "^4.1.2",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^7.2.0",
    "primeicons": "^2.0.0",
    "primeng": "^7.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.23",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.23",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.14",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^8.6.0",
    "@types/google.analytics": "0.0.39",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.1",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.7",
    "ts-loader": "^4.5.0",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3",
    "webdriver-manager": "12.1.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"
  }
```

Hope someone can help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue while upgrading to Angular 9 from Angular 8, I fixed it by upgrading the package that was using it.

Have a look at the nguniversal packages in the dependencies

```
"@nguniversal/common": "^7.1.1",
"@nguniversal/express-engine": "^7.1.1",
"@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^7.1.1",
```

Try upgrading @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader (`ng update @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader`).